# R function for binomial coefficients

Tags: r, sympy

I am trying to compute binomial coefficient using a non-integer `k`, like what [`sympy.functions.combinatorial.factorials.binomial`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/combinatorial.html#binomial) in Python does.

Following the definition of binomial coefficient, I have defined a function:

```
binomial <- function(n, k) {
    return(gamma(n+1)/(gamma(k+1)*gamma(n-k+1)))
}
```

However, this doesn't work when the n is large, given that a very big number will generate while calculating. So, I want to ask if there is any function can work?

Thanks!

Comment: take logs and use `lgamma`, then re-exponentiate at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lgamma` function (logarithm of gamma) exists for exactly this sort of calculation:

```
binomial <- function(n, k) {
  return(gamma(n+1)/(gamma(k+1)*gamma(n-k+1)))
}


binomial(2500, 100)
#NaN


binomial2 <- function(n, k) {
  return(exp(lgamma(n+1)-(lgamma(k+1)+lgamma(n-k+1))))
}


binomial2(2500, 100)
#[1] 8.963002e+180
```